# Prevent Silverlight plugin from hanging browser

Tags: silverlight, loops

In Silverlight infinite recursion may hang the whole browser.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    RecursingMethod1();
}

public void RecursingMethod1()
{
    ...
    RecursingMethod2();
    ...
}

public void RecursingMethod2()
{
    ...
    RecursingMethod1();
    ...
}
```

Calling `SomeMethod()` will lead to infinite recursion loop. In .net framework one will get `System.StackOverflowException`. In Silverlight it just hangs browser (e.g. tab with silverlight plugin cannot be closed, you cannot switch to another tab, the only option left is killing browser). Sandboxing in Google Chrome doesn't help in this situation.

The typical situation is when event is invoked from event handler.

Is there any way to make Silverlight throw `System.StackOverflowException`?

### Edit 1

For simple resursion plugin/browser will crash.

If event is invoked from event handler browser hangs. It seems that there is no *real* recursion in this case, just infinite loop that gobbles plugin/browser resources. There is no way it will ever throw exception.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen StackOverflowException in Silverlight before (though you can't catch it). But if the plugin code is malicious/out of your control, you're not going to prevent it from hanging the browser (without improving browser sandboxing), and if not, can't you just fix the code?

Comment: @NicholasW I need this exception to detect problem source.

Answer (score 0):

The Silverlight plugin will throw a StackOverflowException, just be patient and it will eventually appear.

Comment: In Firefox, Chrome it causes plugin crash. In IE it causes browser crash. But no exception at all.